# The Mark of the Beast

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Legend has it that the Mark of the Beast is the number 666. As a legendary puzzler yourself, you know that this is not the case. As your deductions have revealed, *this* is the Mark of the Beast:
[image]

So, tell me. Where can you find this Beast?

Hint #1:

> It'll take a brilliant idea to solve this one. You might even say...

Hint #2:

> ...it would take a stroke of genius.

Comment: But I'm right here!

Comment: @Avi We found the Beast right here in the comments, I think the riddle is solved! :)

Comment: Why not have an actual puzzle on the real mark of the beast? It has been going for centuries and not many people have figured it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find this beast

> At home

> Where else? We're all on lockdown! Or at least that's what I got when I added a (dashed) stroke and flipped it horizontally and vertically ... [image: result]

Comment: I hope this is correct! This is great...

Comment: @Avi that "o" is sketchy, but i'll let that pass. :P

Comment: I guess you could say it was an alternative o (oAlt, for short)

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, just a series of observations that somebody else may find helpful.

The first hint given says:

> It'll take a brilliant idea to solve this one. You might even say...

This gave me the idea to

> brighten the image and/or mess with contrast

but that did not reveal anything useful. As far as I can tell the picture is solely these black marks on a white background.

Reverse image search also did not yield any convincing results, nor did rotating, flipping, etc. The only interesting thing I found is that when you orient it like this:

[image]

The last two markings seem to say **IF**. But that could just be a coincidence and/or unrelated to the solution.

Other notes:

> The filename when you save the picture is **njw4z**, which may be relevant and seems to resemble a code?

Comment: imgur filenames are usually randomly generated when you add an image to Stack site - I wouldn't worry about going down that rabbit hole!

Comment: @Stiv Ah, whoops. It seemed vaguely codelike so I was curious if it might be related.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the thing about needing a brilliant idea is pointing in a different direction (at a specific phrase) ... though that hasn't enabled me to solve the puzzle as yet, so maybe I'm all wrong.

Comment: (It turned out that I was right about the specific phrase -- but it never occurred to me to make it rot13(n _qnfurq_ fgebxr)!)